# Creating tabs in a sharepoint webpart using multiview

Tags: web-part

I would like to create multiple tabs within a webpart using "Multiview". There are lot of examples available for creating tabs using "Multiview" or "TabControl" but that were in asp.net pages.

So I would like to do the same in webpart, so please suggest how to achieve that functionality.

I have tried the following, it executed but nothing can be viewed inside the web part.

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
  Label lblname = new Label();

  lblname.Text = "testlabel";

  MultiView multiMain = new MultiView();

  View view1 = new View();
  view1.Controls.Add(lblname);

  multiMain.Views.Add(view1);

}
```

Cheers,

Chandra Shekhar

Answer (score 2):

First thing in the above code i observed. You are not adding the controls to Controls collection

this.Controls.Add(yourcreatedcontrol);

Then only the webpart can render your controls

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply. So you mean to say that I need to add "this.Controls.Add(multiMain);" at the end? Please suggest

Comment: Yes, that will do.